# What to do with obsolete question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I asked [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854530/mouse-twitches-frantically-on-click) some time earlier. I didn't get any answers, but by now I found out that the question itself is obsolete, because the problem isn't a Ubuntu config error, but rather a hardware issue. I've since edited the question to reflect this, but I was wondering what the right practice would be; answer it myself, delete it, leave it like this?

It could be useful if others have the same problem, that they can find out it isn't due to configuration issues but rather the hardware. But on the other side, it's not really Ubuntu related (any more).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such questions normally get closed as not reproducible with the following reason statement:

> This describes **a problem that can't be reproduced** that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

As author of the question, you could either vote to close your question yourself (requires you to have at least 250 reputation points though), or you can flag it to be closed by clicking through the flag menu like this:

- flag
- should be closed...
- off-topic because...
- a problem that can't be reproduced

After your flag/close vote has been reviewed, the question will be closed and no more new answers will get accepted.

Theoretically you could also click the "delete" button below your question to immediately delete it (removes it from the list of questions and makes it invisible for all users with less than 10k reputation), but normally we prefer a closed question over a deleted question unless it is really low quality.

If the closed question turns out to be irrelevant to the site (very low view count), it can happen that the Community user bot automatically deletes the question after a specific period of time as well btw.